# image_tag in css definition - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, haml

This is a part of my show.html.haml file:

```
:css
  .parallax-image-1 {
    background: url('/assets/malatesta.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

How do i use the image_tag in the background:url ?

thanks.remco

Answer (score 1):

You would use:

`background: image-url("malatesta.jpg");`

See section 2.3.2 in [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) docs.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What shows up in the css when the page is rendered?

Comment: i see this when i inspect/source code the element/page/css file: parallax-image-1 {
background: image-url("malatesta.jpg");

Comment: is it possibly not to precompile the assets/images?

Comment: `image_url` not `image-url`

Comment: @PeterTretyakov - No, definitely ```image-url```.

Comment: @Remco - What is the extension of your css file? It needs to be ```.scss```.

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate Ruby code to HAML filters with `#{}`

```
background: url(#{image_tag 'path/to/image'});
```

Comment: thanks.don't work for me...i see this in mu source background: url(asset_path('wood.gif'));

Comment: Sorry, I've missed, that it is a HAML filter in `.haml` file. I've updated the answer.